# Can't make motd to show on Debian 8

Tags: debian, services, motd

I have a VPS with debian jessie on it. I want the dynamic motd to show when i connect through ssh. I tried with

```
update-rc.d motd defaults
```

(gives no output), `systemctl enable motd` gives:

```
update-rc.d: warning: enable action will have no effect on runlevel 1
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

`systemctl status motd` says:

```
motd.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

The script is in /etc/rc*.d however. The only way managed to show is by issuing `service motd start` (which creates /var/run/motd.dynamic, does not persists across reboots by the way)

Comment: is the file/script in /etc/init.d?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Sure: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 995 apr  6  2015 /etc/init.d/motd

Answer (score 2):

This is half-baked stuff you can't simply enable.
Refer to the corresponding [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=764841) and the [thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2014/12/msg00368.html) linked from there. You'll have to choose an implementation (`update-motd.d` or custom `pam_exec`) and configure the missing parts.